# Initial Current of Inductor?

Tags: electric-circuits

I know that a capacitor can be charged up to store energy, then if we disconnect the capacitor from the source and hook it up to a light bulb, it will light up since the energy stored is used to power the light bulb. I was wondering whether the same thing would happen if we used an inductor instead?

If so, what is the inital current the moment it is attached to the light bulb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but there are some differences with the case of the capacitor, as follows.

Where a capacitor stores energy in the form of an electric field, an inductor stores energy in the form of a magnetic field. To sustain that magnetic field requires the continuous flow of electrical current through the inductor. If you attempt to stop that current flow so that the magnetic field will collapse, the energy stored in the field will get pumped into the inductor in a direction that strives to maintain the flow of current.

The initial current through the bulb will be the same as the current flow through the inductor without the bulb, after which the bulb will grow dim and go out as the energy stored in the inductor is dissipated by the resistance of the bulb.

This tendency to keep the current flowing is so great that if you try stopping the current by breaking the wire leading to the inductor, a spark will fly between the cut ends of the wire and they may catch fire as a result.